# two extension fields with coprime degrees

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $F$ be a field, and let $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ be irreducible polynomials over $F$ with $\deg{f}=m$ and $\deg{g}=n$ so that $\textrm{gcd}(m,n)=1$. Now, suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ in some extension field over $F$. Prove that $g(x)$ is irreducible over $F(\alpha)$.

I already know that its various well-known 'direct proof'.

But, i wonder if it can be proved using the 'proof by contradiction'.

Starting the assumption : '$g(x)$ is reducible over $F(\alpha)$'.

However, i can't find where to deduce contradictions.

Can anyone help me? or give some comment. Thank you!

Comment: There is only one proof which is that $nm=lcm(n,m)\ | \ [F(\alpha,\beta):F]\le nm$ and $g $ irreducible over $F(\alpha)$ means $[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)] =n$

Comment: also, most direct proofs by students are actually direct ones with 2 extra lines. i.e.: "assume $g(x)$ is irreducible ... but then $g(x)$ is irreducible, which is a contradiction" 
delete the first and last few words and the proof becomes direct